# how to create a dictionary in python with certain values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following two lists in Python

This list contains the titles from a row

```
['id', 'hostname', 'personality', 'action', 'operational', 'availability']
```

This list contains the data from a row

```
['| 1  | hostname_1           | master  | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |', '| 2  | hostname_2 | slave     | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |', '| 3  | hostname_3 | slave     | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |']
```

So far I do not find the way of iterate over the two list in order to get the following result

```
{'id': {'1': {'action': 'unlocked',
              'availability': 'available',
              'hostname': 'hostname_1',
              'operational': 'enabled',
              'personality': 'master'},
        '2': {'action': 'unlocked',
              'availability': 'available',
              'hostname': 'hostname_2',
              'operational': 'enabled',
              'personality': 'slave'},
        '3': {'action': 'unlocked',
              'availability': 'available',
              'hostname': 'hostname_3',
              'operational': 'enabled',
              'personality': 'slave'}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be compatible with Python of version prior to 3.5 or don't want the overhead of using regex, you can use the following dict comprehension instead:

```
t = ['id', 'hostname', 'personality', 'action', 'operational', 'availability']
l = ['| 1  | hostname_1           | master  | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |', '| 2  | hostname_2 | slave     | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |', '| 3  | hostname_3 | slave     | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |']
print({t[0]: {i[0]: dict(zip(t[1:], i[1:])) for i in [[v.strip() for v in i.strip('|').split('|')] for i in l]}})
```

This outputs:

```
{'id': {'1': {'hostname': 'hostname_1', 'personality': 'master', 'action': 'unlocked', 'operational': 'enabled', 'availability': 'available'}, '2': {'hostname': 'hostname_2', 'personality': 'slave', 'action': 'unlocked', 'operational': 'enabled', 'availability': 'available'}, '3': {'hostname': 'hostname_3', 'personality': 'slave', 'action': 'unlocked', 'operational': 'enabled', 'availability': 'available'}}}
```

Comment: if you downvote an accepted answer, you should really leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and `re`:

```
import re
_start, *header = ['id', 'hostname', 'personality', 'action', 'operational', 'availability']
data = ['| 1  | hostname_1           | master  | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |', '| 2  | hostname_2 | slave     | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |', '| 3  | hostname_3 | slave     | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |']
new_data = [re.findall('\w+', i) for i in data]
final_results = {_start:{a:dict(zip(header, b)) for a, *b in new_data}}
```

Output:

```
{'id': {'1': {'hostname': 'hostname_1', 'personality': 'master', 'action': 'unlocked', 'operational': 'enabled', 'availability': 'available'}, '2': {'hostname': 'hostname_2', 'personality': 'slave', 'action': 'unlocked', 'operational': 'enabled', 'availability': 'available'}, '3': {'hostname': 'hostname_3', 'personality': 'slave', 'action': 'unlocked', 'operational': 'enabled', 'availability': 'available'}}}
```

Edit: without Python3.x unpacking:

```
import re
headers = ['id', 'hostname', 'personality', 'action', 'operational', 'availability']
data = ['| 1  | hostname_1           | master  | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |', '| 2  | hostname_2 | slave     | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |', '| 3  | hostname_3 | slave     | unlocked       | enabled     | available    |']
new_data = [re.findall('\w+', i) for i in data]
final_results = {headers[0]:{i[0]:dict(zip(header, i[1:])) for i in new_data}}
```

Comment: looks like that there is something wear because the final_results give me a duplicates keys

Comment: @Israel Dictionaries by definition do not contain duplicate keys. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by converting your data into a "virtual CSV file" with vertical bars as separators:

```
data_as_str = "|" + "|".join(titles) + "|\n" + "\n".join(lst)
```

Next, convert the string into a file-like object and read it using pandas, the Queen of CSVs:

```
import pandas as pd, io
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_as_str), sep="\s*\|\s*", index_col='id')
```

Some phony columns (before the first "|"s and after the last "|"s) have to be removed:

```
data.drop(['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 7'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

All you have to do now is to convert the dataframe into a dictionary:

```
{data.index.name: data.T.to_dict()}
#{'id': {1: {'hostname': 'hostname_1', 'personality': 'master', 
#            'action': 'unlocked',...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your data structure could be greatly improved by transforming your lists into a list of dicts instead of your suggested format because the `id` key is redundant as proposed. This is how it would present in a typical JSON array.

```
results = [
    {
        'action': 'unlocked',
        'availability': 'available',
        'hostname': 'hostname_1',
        'id': '1',
        'operational': 'enabled',
        'personality': 'master'
    },{
        'action': 'unlocked',
        'availability': 'available',
        'hostname': 'hostname_2',
        'id': '2',
        'operational': 'enabled',
        'personality': 'slave'
    },{
        'action': 'unlocked',
        'availability': 'available',
        'hostname': 'hostname_3',
        'id': '3',
        'operational': 'enabled',
        'personality': 'slave'
    }
]
```

As for parsing the strings into lists you don't need regex or anything fancy, simple string methods will suffice. Here is a function that will convert your data into the aforementioned structure.

```
def get_list_of_dicts(headers, rows):
    rows = [[i.strip() for i in row.split('|') if i] for row in rows]
    return [{k: v for k, v in zip(headers, row)} for row in rows]
```